# Reference category or class for multinomial regression

Tags: r, r-caret, multilabel-classification, glmnet, multinomial

Following this
(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125235/glmnet-which-is-the-reference-category-or-class-in-multinomial-regression).

I have 3 categories or classes or responses variable:

- Case (reference group)
- group1
- group2

When I run

```
fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y,family="multinomial", alpha=1) and <- coef(fit, s = bestlambda)
```

I get

> coefs

```
            Case       group1     group2

Feature1    0.10       0.0        0.0

Feature2    0.00       0.20       0.0
```

Here it shows the Feature1 is important for a `Case`, `Feature2` is important for `group2` (coefficient > 0). But I am interested to set a Case as a reference category. Any suggestions?